# Making custom chrome app top bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am making a chrome app and this is my background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'outerBounds': {
            'width': 500,
            'height': 500,
        },
        'resizable': false
    });
});
```

I want to know how to make it so when I run the app, the top bar where you can close the app is a different color. I also want to know how to show text on the top bar with a different color.

Answer (score 0):

The top bar is part of the window's *frame*.

You can supply a [`FrameOptions`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-FrameOptions) object to `create()`:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'outerBounds': {
            'width': 500,
            'height': 500,
        },
        'resizable': false,
        'frame': { /* ... */ }
    });
});
```

You have 2 broad options:

- You can keep the default system frame, and have (minimal) customization options: specifically, you can control the frame's color. See [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/window-options).

  ```
  'frame': { 'color': "#ff0000" }
  ```

  Optionally, it can be different when active/inactive. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-FrameOptions) for appropriate format. You can't control the text color this way.
- You can completely disable the OS-supplied frame, and build your own - but you'll need to provide your own controls (e.g. a close button) and [draggable areas](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#draggable). See [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window).

  ```
  'frame' : { 'type' : 'none' }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

innerBounds: {
        width: ,
        height: ,
        minWidth: ,
        maxWidth: ,
        minHeight: ,
        maxHeight: 
}